# Conditional forms with jQuery (on selecting an <option>, show element)

Tags: jquery

Riddle me this: How can I use jQuery to display an element ONLY when a specific option is selected in a  box?

.click clearly isn't the right event— but i've been hunting around and can't find out to work with form options.

EX:

```
  $('option[name="publish_on"]').click(function(){
      $('.secret').fadeIn();
  })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('your selects class or id').change(function(){    
    if($(this).val() == "publish_on"){
        $('.secret').fadeIn();
    }
    else{
        $('.secret').hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `.change` function ..  http://jqapi.com/#p=change

```
$(function(){
    $('#opts').change(function(){
        var $val = $(this).val();
        if($val === 'A'){
             $('.1').show();   
        }
        // ...
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2x23P/1/

Answer (score 2):

Use the change event:

```
$('#idOfSelect').on('change', function() {
  var selected = $(this).val();
  if ($(selected).is('option[name="publish_on"]')) {
    $('.secret').fadeIn();
  } else {
    $('.secret').fadeOut();
  }
});
```